# XMLHTTPRequest loading local file in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

So the XMLHttpRequest shouldn't work for loading local files for websites.  It would be a crazy security risk if a person could actually gain access to a user's file system via JavaScript.

But for whatever reason when I use a XMLHttpRequest to load a local text file in a chrome extension it works.  **Why is it that when I use XMLHttpRequest for a chrome extension in the background script it loads the file?**  Is this a security flaw or is it intentional?  And doesn't this create similar security risks as having the request load local files in a web-page?

Let me try to explain this in the best way I can:

I have a text file called `abc.txt` and I want to open it and read the file contents via JavaScript so I decided to use an XMLHttpRequest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
</script>
  <script>
    let txt = '';
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log(txt)
            }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "abc.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the usual error, `test.html:17 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/none/of/your/business/abc.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

However when I make a chrome extension I can load the local file via the background.js script.

manifest.js file:

```
{
    "name": "Question",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    }
}
```

background.js file:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    let txt = '';
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
                console.log(txt)
            }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "abc.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

proof that text file is loaded:
[image]

To restate my question, why does XMLHttpRequests treat the chrome extension's background.js script differently?  Does't it create similar problems as having XMLHttpRequests on a web page?

NOTE:  The XMLHttpRequest only seems to only work in the background.js file, the minute I link the file to a HTML document it stops functioning and I get the normal error message.  So I can't run it on the popup html file.

Comment: this is one example that shows web extensions have **less restrictions** on them

Comment: CORS requests are allowed for extensions background scripts

Answer (score 0):

As according to Deliaz the answer was that chrome allows CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

It can only access files in the extension's own directory. These files are part of the extension. If you try to access files in other places with the `file://` protocol, you get an error `Not allowed to load local resource`. So you cannot actually gain access to a user's file system.
[image]

Comment: This is the way how browsers should work for everything: for example if I make a **local html - js application** and I store into the same dir some other files it would be great to have the possibility to access them with no CORS restrictions from the application it self. Maybe a notification message to allow such an access should be shown from the browser asking for permission, indicating the targeted directory by the application, Such permission will be granted or not by the user each time opens the app, similarly to the permission to use the microphone.